# Don't know how to get rid of these {} in a list (python2.7)

Tags: python, list, brackets

Ive tried converting the lists into strings, but I just cant seem to get rid of the brackets:

```
import Tkinter
import random
window = Tkinter.Tk()
window.geometry("250x150")
window.title("Backstory_Generator")
window.config(bg="black")

Race=Tkinter.Entry(window, bd=10)#gui stuff
Racee=Tkinter.Label(window,text="Race")
Racee.config(bg="Black", fg="White")
Race.config(bg="Grey")


Class=Tkinter.Label(window,text="Class")#gui stuff
Clas=Tkinter.Entry(window,bd=10)
Class.config(bg="Black", fg="White")
Clas.config(bg="Grey")

def Select():
    text1 = random.randint(0,len(pb1)-1)
    text2=random.randint(0,len(pb2)-1)#picks random number for word
    text3=random.randint(0,len(pb3)-1)
    text4 = random.randint(0,len(pb4)-1)
    RaceChosen = Race.get()#retreus what entered
    ClassChosen = Clas.get()
    Result = Tkinter.Tk()#new window
    Result.title("Result")
    Result.config(bg="Black")
    lol = "You are a",RaceChosen,"who has chosen to path of the",ClassChosen,"\n","you are " + pb1[text1] + " and craving for " + pb2[text2] + " ,You also are extremely " + pb3[text3] + " around others","\n","due to your " + pb4[text4] + " tendancies"
    Line1 = Tkinter.Label(Result, text=lol)#outputs random thing
    Line1.config(font=("Courier",15, "bold"))
    Line1.config(bg="Black", fg="White", height = 10)
    Line1.pack()
    Result.geometry=("1000x250")
    Result.mainloop()

Generate = Tkinter.Button(window, text="Generate", command=Select)

Racee.pack()
Race.pack()
Class.pack()
Clas.pack()
Generate.pack()


window.mainloop()
```

As you will see, the brackets create a strange look that I can't seem to get rid of. I'm aware this question has been asked multiple times, but converting the list into a string and using the .join(map) didnt work for me.
Any suggestions? I left the lists out because they contain some explicit material, so yeah :P

[The output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/poJvo.png)

Answer (score 5):

Look at this line:

```
lol = "You are a",RaceChosen,"who has chosen to path of the",ClassChosen,"\n","you are " + pb1[text1] + " and craving for " + pb2[text2] + " ,You also are extremely " + pb3[text3] + " around others","\n","due to your " + pb4[text4] + " tendancies"
```

You're creating a tuple not a string.

Comment: You can fix this by using string interpolation. `"You are a %s who has chosen to path of the %s\n you are (and etc)" % (RaceChosen, ClassChosen, ...)`

Comment: How would I change it? Sorry, im kinda new

Comment: Can  you give me an example of a bit of the code, like how would i define the % as racechosen, or classchosen?

Comment: I got this error: Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk/Tkinter.py", line 1540, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "/home/cam/Documents/Python files/Character Generator.py", line 34, in Select
    lol = "You are a %s who has chosen to path of the %s \n you are %s and craving for %s ,You also are extremely %s around others","\n","due to your %s tendancies" % (RaceChosen, ClassChosen, pb1[text1], pb2[text2], pb3[text3], pb4[text4])
TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting

Comment: With this :    lol = "You are a %s who has chosen to path of the %s \n you are %s and craving for %s ,You also are extremely %s around others","\n","due to your %s tendancies" % (RaceChosen, ClassChosen, pb1[text1], pb2[text2], pb3[text3], pb4[text4])

Comment: Ive now got an error: not enough arguments for string formatting

Comment: Then debug it and fix it.